# VueJS: computed property using another computed property isn't working correctly

Tags: vuejs2, computed-properties

this is not these: [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282378/vuejs-computed-property-based-on-other-computed-property), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46743282/vuejs-computed-properties-that-depend-on-other-asynchronous-computed-propertie)

i'm building a small SPA and so i started with this basic principle that i tested and built up into the code farther below that i'm having problems with.  it works ONLY if i call the secondary property in the DOM (why??) and i've included it to illustrate where i started from, hoping that the principles would translate as i built up.

JS:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    today: function() {
      return new Date().getTime();
    },
    tomorrow: function() {
      return this.today + (1*24*60*60*1000);
  },
});
```

DOM:

```html
<div id='app'>
  <p>{{ today }}</p>
  <p>{{ tomorrow }}</p>
</div>
```

so.  that works.  again, ONLY if `app.tomorrow` is called in the DOM.  (wish i knew how NOT to need that...) BUT my problem is this next part, which i based on this starter code.  **it** *DOESN'T* work:

JS:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dueNow: 0,
    reports: { 90: [], 'DN': [] },
  },
  computed: {
    today() {
      return new Date().getTime();
    },
    tMinus30() {
      return new Date().getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    },
    dueNow() {
      var count = 0;

      $.each(this.rows, function(index, obj) {
        var workingDate = new Date(obj.dateSubmitted).getTime();
        console.log('workingDate: '+workingDate);
        console.log('today: '+this.today);      <-- console reports 'undefined'!?
        console.log('today: '+this.tMinus30);   <-- console reports 'undefined'!?

        if(workingDate < this.today && workingDate > this.tMinus30){
          console.log('knock, knock: due NOW');   <-- therefore this never fires
          count++;
          console.log('count: '+count);

          //  build reports array - doesn't work, but that's for another day...
          this.reports['DN']['count'] = push(count);
          this.reports['DN'][index]['reportID'] = push(obj.id);
          this.reports['DN'][index]['assetID'] = push(obj.assetid);
        }
      });
      return count;
    },
  }
});
```

DOM:

```html
<div id='app'>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
  <h1 class="text-center pt-2">NOW</h1>
  <p>{{ today.getDay() }}</p>
  <p class="img-text mb-1" @click="expandInfo('DN')">{{ dueNow }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

so not only am i not getting the `count` of rows that are `dueNow`, i'm not getting `today.getDay()` calculated either, which, based on [this from VueJS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions), should work.  i suspect this is a flying nightmare, but i don't see it...  it DOES iterate over the rows properly.  it DOES calculate the working date for each row.  but nothing else works.  i thought i understood VueJS well enough to attempt this.  and i even built it up from the first example... but i'm at a loss as to what's broken.

what principle am i overlooking to make this gel?  it feels like some concept has eluded me.

EDIT:  i also perused [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181182/vuejs-form-computed-property) but don't know that it applies as there's nothing that isn't declared in the data already...

EDIT:  OK! :)  i need to clarify.  when i say "it doesn't work", what i mean is the computed property `tomorrow` does not render and reports the other computed property in the console as "undefined", despite it (`today`) rendering just fine (without the additional method).  my expected/desired result is that i will see a number indicating how many rows passed muster and are `dueNow` and i want to see the `today` rendered as "Monday" and `tomorrow` as "Tuesday" (for example).  this last should be interchangeable with other date functions.  if possible, i'd also like to have the array `reports` update properly... but that's out of scope right now.

Comment: The `this` value inside the function created by `$.each(this.rows, function(index, obj) {` will not be the same as it is in the surrounding function. If you use an arrow function instead, i.e. `$.each(this.rows, (index, obj) => {` the `this` binding will be correct. Alternative ways to bind the `this` value are available if you want to avoid arrow functions. This isn't a Vue thing, just standard JS `this` binding.

Comment: This part of the template doesn't make sense to me: `{{ today.getDay() }}`. The computed property `today` is a number, so it won't have a `getDay` method. I assume you were aiming for the `getDay` method of `Date` but `today` is not a `Date`. It does initially create a `Date` but then it calls `getTime`, which just returns a number.

Comment: As for why your original example needs `tomorrow` in your template, you'd need to provide a clearer explanation of exactly what you mean by *'works'* and what happens when it *'doesn't work'*. Personally I wouldn't use a computed property for that in the first place as it has no reactive dependencies so can never be updated. I'd just put `today` in `data` instead.

Comment: @skirtle regarding the `today.getDate` issue: *facepalm*... you're right!  i expected it to simply render the number back into a Date and then... well, you get the idea.  okay.  i'll fix that.  thanks!  makes total sense now that i see it.

Comment: @skirtle i have no problems with arrow functions other than i haven't used them much.  i have been doing mostly PHP and Python stuff lately, so it didn't occur to me.  i'll brush up and deploy!  hopefully this will yield fruit in fixing other issues like the array...  :P

Comment: @skirtle i didn't know `data` could hold a "computed" property like that.  i also wasn't too worried as the data is meant to be static until the next time it's loaded.  although, if i can be transposed into data as-is, then i'm happy to bring along all the extra goodness that comes with doing that.  i'll test tonight and post my findings.